# a number between 0 and 1 as a type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Can I declare a type that between 0 and 1 or any other to integer values in typescript

for example

```
interface Config { 
    opacity : =>0 && <=1     //<= something like this
}
```

Comment: Looks like it was suggested some time ago: [Suggestion: Range as Number type #15480](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480). But I don't believe it is a current capability.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's possible. However, if you only need certain numbers you can do this:

```
type Opacity = 0|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.4|0.5|0.6|0.7|0.8|0.9|1;

let myVar:Opacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a wrapper class which throws an error if the number is out of range:

```
class Opacity {
    readonly num: number;

    constructor(num: number) {
       if(num < 0 || num > 1) {
           throw new Error("Number out of range");
       }

       this.num = num;
    }
}

var good = new Opacity(0.5);

var bad = new Opacity(2.5); // error
```

Comment: this is the correct approach